# Counting uppercase words and punctuation in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I've used this website for a long time to solve my Excel issues but haven't been able to find a solution for the following problems.
I've text strings (ranging from ca. 5 words to 1000 words long) in cells B16 to B936.
I want to achieve two things :

1. count for each cell the occurrences of words in capitalized letters
   that are longer than two characters. So basically `"I find that 
   StackOverflow is a really GREAT website"` would return the score `"1"`
   since `"GREAT"` is the only word in this text string that is longer
   than 2 characters and in capitalized letters
2. count the number of times multiple question marks `("??", "???",
   "????", ...)` appear in those text strings. Exemple : `"Are you sure
   ?? Really sure ???" would return the score "2"`. I've tried to use a
   forumla `(LEN - LEN(Substitute(..;"??"))` but obviously when this
   formula encounters a `"????"` it returns an odd result.

Comment: I think this is hilarious. I am interested to know the results of the actual report you are conducting using this data.

Comment: What is the layout going to look like when you return the results?  1) goes to "C" 2) goes to "D"?

Comment: Can you give a definitive list of all punctuation marks which may be present within that column of data?

Comment: "I've used this website for a long time to solve my Excel issues" but it is your first question and you are member since...today. And your provide no code or try.

Comment: @  PJ Rosenburg : block letters and multiple punctuation are used as proxy for emotions (mostly negative ones) in writing. Existing metanorms compute valence and interaction based on words and other artifacts are not taken into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
Function CountUppercaseWords(Expression As String) As Integer
    Dim SplitArray() As String
    SplitArray = Split(Expression, " ")
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim NextWord As String
    Count = 0
    For I = LBound(SplitArray) To UBound(SplitArray)
        NextWord = SplitArray(I)
        If NextWord = UCase(NextWord) And Len(NextWord) >= 2 Then
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Next
    CountUppercaseWords = Count
End Function

Function MultipleQuestionMarkOccurences(Expression As String) As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim CurrentLength As Integer
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim NextChar As String
    Count = 0
    CurrentLength = 0
    For I = 1 To Len(Expression)
        NextChar = Mid(Expression, I, 1)
        If NextChar = "?" Then
            CurrentLength = CurrentLength + 1
        Else
            CurrentLength = 0
        End If
        If CurrentLength = 2 Then
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Next
    MultipleQuestionMarkOccurences = Count
End Function
```

Comment: I'm no expert in VBA, but see my question to the OP above re punctuation. For example, will this solution also ignore the string "IS!" - which I assume should not be considered as part of the count - from cases such as "Do you know of any great websites? Yes! StackOverflow IS!"?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. First you will have to strip all punctuation from Expression. Also define punctuation.

Comment: @ XOR LX : good point. Thank you. the analysis being carried out on  pieces of text that are in French, anything of more than 2 characters in uppercase is of interest. The example you gave is not really something that applies to French language. Is it something usual in English and what would be the meaning of it ? Is there any emotional meaning attached to "IS!" ?

Comment: What he meant is my method counts any characters that are not whitespace as a part of word.

Comment: Hello,I've tested the UDf. The one for the question marks works fine. Thank you. However with the one for the UppercaseWords the issue is that it counts also numbers. For instance if you consider the text string "I'm HAPPY to be here with 1245 other people" it returns the score 2 because it considers that 1245 is also an uppercase word. How can we get rid of this problem ?

Comment: I think that could be solved if we replace all characters that are not a uppercase or lowercase letter with a whitespace. Do you have any extra fancy characters that can be regarded as a part of a word (i.e. characters with accents)?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't perfect solution, but maybe helpful.
    Public Function CountUpperWords(ByVal String1 As String) As Integer

```
Dim StringArray() As String
ReDim StringArray(Len(String1)) As String
Dim String2 As String
Dim String2Array() As String
ReDim String2Array(UBound(StringArray)) As String
Dim isUpper As Boolean
String2 = UCase(String1)

For i = 0 To Len(String1) ' fragmentation all text to array and make UCase mirror 
    StringArray(i) = Mid(String1, i + 2, 1) 'Function would start from secound character because first character often will be upper
    String2Array(i) = LCase(StringArray(i))
Next

CountUpperCases = 0

For i = 0 To UBound(StringArray) ' compare original text and upper
    If StringArray(i) <> String2Array(i) Then
        j = i
        isUpper = False
        Do While StringArray(j) <> " " ' checking word is upper
            If StringArray(j) <> String2Array(j) Then
                isUpper = True
                Else
                isUpper = False
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        If isUpper = True Then
                CountUpperCases = CountUpperCases + 1
            End If
        i = j
    End If
Next

End Function
```